# Is this an optimal table structure? (Dynamic table properties)

Tags: sql, database-design

I wish to store the data of two (different) classes, but with several shared properties, in the same database tabel.

A rough look on the system classes:

```
JobApplication : IActivity
Id: Int
ActivityType : Int
Title : String
CompanyName : String
CompanyAdress : String

Meeting : IActivity
Id: Int
ActivityType : Int
Title : String
Text : String
```

The classes both have a few properties in common: ActivityType and Title

The following is my idea of the database structure for these classes, to keep them in the same table:

```
Table: Activity
Id : Int
ActivityTypeId : Int

Table: Properties
Id : Int
PropertyName : Int (Title, Text, CompanyName etc)

Table: ActivityProperties
Id : Int
ActivityId : Int
PropretyId : Int
Value : String

Table: ActivityType
Id : Int
Title : String

Table: ActivityTypeProperties
Id : Int
ActivityId : Int
PropertyId : Int
```

The idea is that activities have their property values set through the ActivityProperties and the ActivityTypeProperties defines what properties an activity should have.

Would you say this is an optimal structure, if not, do you have any ideas to a better solution? I wanna prioritize keeping the data of activities in the same table and not having to create a database table for each activitytype.

Comment: What you have there in ActivityTypeProperties is formally known as Entity Attribute Value (EAV). There are circumstances where it's a practical choice, but it can cause a whole rash of problems. Google EAV database, look at the pros and cons, see which it is for you.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer. I did not know that this pattern was called EAV. Thank you for making that clear!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? With Postgres you might want to consider using `hstore` instead (an efficient key/value store as a column data type)

Comment: not really an answer. We would need to know much more before we could take a foolish guess. In general though EAV in a relational db, is something that should make you pause.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with creating a separate table for each activity type? Will these types be created and deleted on the fly by the users? If so, then yes, you want a type to be a record that can be inserted or deleted from a table. Otherwise, if the types are stable, then it's much easier to make a table for each type with one "super" table to hold attributes which the types have in common. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014676/what-is-the-correct-way-to-design-a-table-to-row-relationship/30041756#30041756) for details.